# Know the displaying items in thumbnail carousel

Tags: jquery, css

My working carousel has structure something like this

```
<ul class="carousel">
  <li><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
```

And at a time three of the thumbnail displays. And on clicking next-prev, or in default there is no difference on the list (like no classes are added for displaying three or hasn't displayed none to other). And i have to focus the middle one from the one displaying in the carousel.
[image]

So my question is how can i recognize which `li's` are being displaying.

**What i tried :** 
I only could achieve on hovering effect as i can use the `hover` event to trigger other siblings to go blur.

And i am planning to include opacity block with `before & after` with wrapper but still these doesn't look appropriate solution

**Edit:** I am using [owl carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html)

Comment: Are you using a carousel plugin? If so which one, it may have a built in method for this many of them do. Also, can you create a jsfiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: which slider you are using? so that we can see demo and let you know because with this code it is difficult to investigate

Comment: @DelightedD0D i am using owl carousel, i have also updated question.

Comment: @YogeshSharma i am using owl carousel, i have also updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the owl plugin is not as straightforward about this as some other plugins. However, the below will do what you need. Basically, you can provide an `afterAction` option that is a function that gets called after the slide changes.

Ive used this function to detect the current slide index internally on the change event and add it as a data attribute on the target element.

When you click the button, it gets that index from the element and uses it with jQuery's `.eq()` to find the current `.item` element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var owl = $("#owl-demo"),
    status = $("#owlStatus");

  owl.owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    afterAction: function() {
      owl.data('currentItem', this.owl.currentItem);
    }
  });

  $('#getCurrent').click(function() {
    var cur = owl.data('currentItem') || 0; // the "or 0" here makes sure that there is an initial value if the user selects something before changing the slider at all
    var $currentItem = owl.find('.item').eq(cur);
    $currentItem.addClass('red');
    console.log($currentItem);
  });

});
```

#### [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/8bJUc/560/)

See [How to retrieve basic information from plugin (current, prev, all items, visible items etc.)](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/owlStatus.html) for information on what other properties you can access internally in that function

Comment: Yeah from this link http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/owlStatus.html `visibileItems` looks promising. Thank you.